# How can I minimize time while copying data using pipeline from cosmos source to cosmos sink in azure data factory

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, data-migration

I am working on copying data from one Azure Cosmos database to another Azure Cosmos Database. The RUs set at source and destination are 800 and 15000 respectively and the container that I am copying has 3GB data and 4 million documents.

While copying through Azure data factory directly from source to destination, it takes forever so I added staging (Azure blob storage) and set the DTUI and parallelization as auto. Copying is quick to Blob storage but while copying from blob storage to Cosmos, the throughput is 3Mbps which keeps reducing to 600 kbps as data size increases.

How can I improve the throughput and minimize time taken for copying. It took me 1 hr 15 mins to copy 3GB data.

Comment: Are your two Cosmos DB accounts in the same region? Have you tried adjusting the Data Integration Unit (DUI) setting? Have you examined your Cosmos DB statistics to see if inserts are being throttled?

Comment: Yes both of them are in same region.Auto works better though but yes we gave a try on that setting but error 429 graph never goes down.In the metrics , I see the graph of http 429 at 30k.

Answer (score 0):

Try this data loading operation using data flows. When using CosmosDB as source or sink in a data flow, you can set the RU throughout for the operation, enabling scale-up during the pipeline run.

We also allow throttling limits per Spark partition. Because data flows uses the CosmosDB Spark bulk API, you can control Spark paritioning in your source & sink as well as CosmosDB throughput. You'll see partitioning options in the Optimize tab.

Those additional controls may give you better performance for your operation. You should test this with a smaller subset of your data against the copy operation rather than trying to load the fill 3GB/4M dataset for this testing.

Comment: sure will try this out.Thanks